# Not able to Format Date created by Facebook, Returns NULL date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

Facebook provides date objects in the format: `2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000`

I want to convert this format to NSDate.

I am using the following code. Why does it return `null`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" +"];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '+'ZZZZ"];
NSLog(@"%@",df.dateFormat);
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@ date",date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `'+'ZZZZ` with `+zzzz` in your code..

```
    NSString *dateString=@"2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000";

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" +"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"];
    NSLog(@"%@",df.dateFormat);
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];

    NSLog(@"%@ date",date);
```

Output is :

```
2016-04-30 14:52:10.118 date[2523:187669] 2010-12-01 21:35:43 +0000
2016-04-30 14:52:10.120 date[2523:187669] yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz
2016-04-30 14:52:10.153 date[2523:187669] 2010-12-01 21:35:43 +0000 date
```

Comment: This may happen to work with the time zone of `+0000`, but doesn't work in the general case. What if the original date string was `2010-12-01T21:35:43-0500` or `2010-12-01T21:35:43+0100`? In that case, the above would not work. The `+` should not be in the `dateFormat`. You should use `Z` or `ZZZ` instead of `+zzzz`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace any character in string

Try out this code:

Objective-C

```
NSString *dateString=@"2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@ date",date);
```

Swift:

```
let dateString: String = "2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000"
let df: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
let date: NSDate = df.dateFromString(dateString)!
print("date: \(date)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` for your `dateFormat` and don't mess around with the string manipulation at all.

The only thing you might want to do is set the `locale` as outlined in Apple's [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html), so that this will work regardless of what sort of calendar settings the device might otherwise have:

```
df.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Comment: Why the down vote? With all due deference to the accepted answer, it simply perpetuates the inefficient code of the OP.  And the `+zzzz` of the accepted answer won't work unless the time zone represented in the original string was `+0000`. You should use `Z` (as shown above) or `ZZZ`.